# Laravel returns 419 csrf token mismatch after vue axios request

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i'm trying to send an post request from my vue application using axios. I have catched a csrf token from laravel api before and then send this csrf token in the request. Laravel returns with 419 even though my preflight option request returns 204.

This is my request code:

```
export default axios => ({
  csrfToken: null,

  login (email, password) {
    this.callFunc(function () {
      axios.post('http://localhost:6080/auth', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response
      })
    })
  },

  callFunc (callback) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:6080/token').then(response => {
      this.csrfToken = response.data

      axios.defaults.headers.common = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'x-csrf-token': this.csrfToken,
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      }

      callback()
    })
  }
})
```

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: I've also tried to send the csrf token as a post content (_token) like the laravel documentation said. Same result.

Comment: `csrfToken: null` May I know you intention while writing this line? Why is it set to `null`? And is even `csrfToken` a valid parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the page header:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" id="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

inside the `script` tag add:

```
window.Laravel = {csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}'}
```

and the `axios` request:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:6080/auth', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        csrf_token:window.Laravel
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response
      })
```